# Problem with accent in portuguese

Tags: accents, characters

I'm making some document in portuguese. Everything is working fine, but when I open the PDF and try to copy the characters, those with accent make some mess. What I mean is that I write, for exemple, "ação", it's shows in the PDF "ação", but if I try to copy this word from the PDF then I get "a,c~ao". Below you find my code. How can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}
Some words in portuguese with accent: ação, está, cabeça, hélice.
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** The solution is, as one can see in the comments below, adding:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

This way, it is not necessary install cm-super.

Comment: add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`,

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This produce characters with very poor render.

Comment: If the T1 fonts are not rendering correctly you probably do not have the type1 scalable versions installed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I install this?

Comment: Install the cm-super package.

Comment: Searching in internet about T1 fonts, I found that is not necessary to instal cm-super package. It is sufficient to add `\usepackage{lmodern}`. So the complete solution to add to my code is: 
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
`\usepackage{lmodern}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` changes the font encoding. The default is very limited (128 glyphs) and does not contain accented characters.